# Parameter involved in the SHA256_cert_fingerprint for the app link verification

Tags: android, android-studio, sha, applinks, android-app-links

I wanted to support app link feature for my android application and while using App-link Assitant tool in the android studio, and while signing the apk I was using my own generated *.jks file. I found there is a field SHA256_cert_fingerprint. I wanted to know what is the paramter involved in calculating SHA256_cert_fingerprint.
I tried calculating using online SHA256 calculator with the following paramters separately but it was not matching with the SHA256 value shown in the image

- *.jks
- private key
- certificate
- public key
- *.csr

[Screenshot for the SHA 256 value calculated by android studio for implementing app link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz9CW.png)

Does anyone know what are the actual parameters involved in calculating SHA256_cert_fingerprint value? So, that again when I compute the hash through online SHA256 calculator, when compared with the image, I will get the exact match.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of Android Apps, when we sign the app it can be signed through a Java Keystore file (*.jks) which contains the public/private key. So, now I tried to export the certificate using the command

```
keytool -exportcert –alias aliasname -keystore fileUsedToSignApp.jks -file outputFile.cer
```

Now, if we will compute the hash of the document outputFile.cer through some  [available online tool](https://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator), it will be of the same value as shown in the screenshot (mentioned in the question)
Reference: I got the command from the [link](https://www.opencodez.com/java/read-x509-certificate-java-keystore.htm)